# The side wire screws on my power terminal won't tighten?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

[image]

I'm trying to add a second plug off of this one. I've done this dozens of times (yes, it's got plenty of space on the circuit). I prefer the side screw method. I loosened the screws, which were tightened down all the way, and they refuse to catch and go back in.

This is a brand new plug with the test/reset switch. What on earth am I doing wrong? Have I broken the connectors forever? Even the ground is failing to tighten. I wasn't particularly rough or anything, though they were pretty tight before I opened them up. Thanks in advance.

(yes, I realize the input wires are using the port metbod. It's a pain to pull them out, so I'm planning on leaving them.)

Comment: I've never stripped threads on one of these, but I suppose there's a first time. Do the threads look good? Does push and screw help?

Comment: The "port method" is what we call "back stab". Nobody really likes back stabs because they are unreliable. If this is with test/reset then it sounds like a GFCI, in which case there may be a separate issue of "Line" vs. "Load". Can you upload a picture of the back so we can get the make/model #?

Comment: When you backed off the screw before, was it stiff to turn, and did you turn pretty hard?

Answer (score 3):

There is a small plate or clamp that presses the conductor between itself and a contact plate. Make sure you conductor is not behind this plate instead of between the two clamp points. Also you may have backed this plate off of the screw and now it is floating and won't tighten up.

Hope this helps.